# Shell Script: how to expand a variable into quotes

Tags: shell-script, quoting, variable

Can anyone tell me how can I make the follow command to work properly?

```
SERVER=192.168.1.1

ping $SERVER (It Works)

ping '$SERVER' (It doesn't work)
```

I want this to compose a more complex command that needs quotes!

Thank you all!!

Comment: What is the more complex command?

Comment: "I want this to compose a more complex command" -- read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes.

When you use single quotes, you get exactly what you typed, whilst double quotes interpolate, per the example below:-

```
$ x=1
$ echo 'This is $x'
This is $x
$ echo "This is $x"
This is 1
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm looking for @Paul T... but the command need to execute inside single quotes: 'ping $SERVER', the variable need to be expanded inside them... 'ping 192.168.1.1'...

Comment: Why can't the command be in double quotes instead of singles? What's the wider context that forces you to use single quotes? If you can show that, perhaps I can help. BTW I upvoted your question.

Comment: @Kellyson variable expansion does not happen inside single-quotes, so you can not use single quotes here.  This is not a matter of preference or options, or something that can be worked around somehow - it's how single-quotes work, and it's what they're for.   Use double quotes.

Comment: @Paul T, thanks for answer. The command I want to use is:

#ssh -t $SRV1 'ping $SRV2'

The remote SSH command execution requires single quotes.
If I use #ssh -t $SRV1 'ping 192.168.1.2' it works, but I need use a variable for SRV2.

Thank you!

Comment: @Kellyson no, ssh does not require a single quote.  ssh doesn't require any quotes unless you need to control if/how word splitting, file globbing, and/or variable expansion etc happen.   Try `ssh -t "$SRV1" ping "$SRV2"`.   BTW, if you need the remote host to see the double-quote (e.g. when the ssh command uses a remote variable), use `\ ` to escape the double-quote inside the quoted command.  e.g. `ssh "$SRV1" "echo \$HOSTNAME: pinging $SRV2; ping $SRV2"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use double-quotes like so:

```
SERVER=192.168.1

ping "$SERVER.1"
ping "$SERVER".1
ping $SERVER.1
```

Notice the last example has no quotes.

However, see [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash) for a much more in-depth reading on the topic.