# Why is my bash variable not expanded when used in this variable assignment?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync, variable

I'm working to make a small script to transfer some files with `rsync`. I'm stuck with a variable issue.

- I have the folder: `/home/folder_1/`, which have the folders `20210725`, `20210726`, `20210727` and those will increment every day.
- In every one of those folders I have a folder named `folder_2` and inside it are the files that i want to transfer.
- An example for full path: `/home/folder_1/20210727/folder_2/*`

As I need to make the transfer from machine 1 to machine 2 every day, I want to put the script in a cron and run it automatically every day.

To take the day of today in account, I write:

```bash
y=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
m=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
d=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
BASEDATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
DATA=$(eval "echo $BASEDATE")
```

So if I say `echo $DATA`, it return `20210727` for today: 27 July 2021

But, when I put in a variable like that:

```
VAR_1='/home/folder_1/${DATA}/folder_2/*'
```

it is not working. `echo $VAR_1` will return

```
/home/folder_1/${DATA}/folder_2/*
```

instead of what I want:

```
/home/folder_1/20210727/folder_2/*
```

I need that because my rsync command is like that:

```
rsync -av user@machine_1:${VAR_1} ${VAR_2}
```

and `VAR_2` is the path to the new location on the `machine_2`:

```
VAR_2='/home/folder_3/folder_4/'
```

I just cannot figure out how to use the variable to return the correct path, with the date for every day.

Can you please help/advise in some way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell Script: how to expand a variable into quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425561/shell-script-how-to-expand-a-variable-into-quotes)

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that the problem is marked as "solved". If not, please add a comment to explain where you need further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are experiencing is that variable expansion is disabled in single quotes. So, your assignment

```
VAR_1='/home/folder_1/${DATA}/folder_2/*'
```

should be changed to

```
VAR_1="/home/folder_1/${DATA}/folder_2/*"
```

instead. The double-quotes will still inhibit expansion of the glob characters (`*`) which is necessary since you want to pass this as an argument to `rsync`.

As a side-note:

- It is recommended not to use all-uppercase names for shell variables unless you want to export them to the environment (imagine accidentally overwriting `PATH` e.g.).
- When using shell variables (cf. your `rsync` invocation), it is recommended to [double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) them unless you want word splitting to happen. In most cases when dealing with filenames, you do not want that to happen, because the `space` is an allowed character in filenames.
- You are mixing the old-style `` `...` `` and new-style `$( ... )` notation for command substitutions. It is [recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) to stick to the new style because that allows for ease of nesting.
- It is unclear why you would need the

  ```
  DATA=$(eval "echo $BASEDATE")
  ```

  at all. It should be sufficient to simply assign

  ```
  DATA=$(date +%Y%m%d)
  ```